# Table Elements and Unordered Lists cannot be viewed properly on all versions of Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

I'd like to ask if anyone knows why the table elements and unordered lists cannot be viewed properly on ALL VERSIONS of Internet Explorer? The table cells go dark and the unordered lists look really messy.

I have a website that clearly shows this:

http://www.feimediasolutions.com/Dairen_Website/products_rheem85vp.htm

Help is deeply appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is restricted with the shortcut color code. Try changing from #fff to #ffffff:

Change `<tr bgcolor="#fff"> to <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">`

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) explaining the "display" css property:

> Note: The values "inline-table", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", "table-row-group", and "inherit" are not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.

To clarify - your tables are using these css styles and I would suggest trying without them and leave the display at default.  See what happens and go from there.

Comment: fantastic!! how about the unordered lists? any idea why they go messy in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot so I can see what it looks like for you in IE?  I'm not sure what "messy" means lol

Comment: how do I post a screenshot here? I'm new to StackOverflow and I haven't got much credits to post an image

Comment: Go to www.imgur.com or flickr or photobucket or whatever then post that link

Comment: ok I've got one in Dropbox, here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fbya77m50hcd60c/messy_lists.jpg

Comment: This appears to be a case of not enough CSS.  The two side images are floating left and right which leaves the middle text by itself and nothing other than those two divs have any pixels measured out for anything.  I wish I had time to just dive in and get you all the best measurements but I gotta sleep I'm sorry.  I'll try to come back again and see how it's going though.